# How do I create a grid and rotate it 90deg N amount of times in python?

Tags: python

I will have an array input for example

```
4 3 1
6 5 2
9 7 3
```

I need to rotate this grid 90deg N amount of times without numpy.

Output:

```
1 2 3
3 5 7
4 6 9
```

```
N = int(input())

measurements = []
for i in range(N):
    item = list(map(int, input().split()))
    measurements.append(item)

def rotate90(measurements):
    newList = []
    for i in range(N-1):
        for j in range(N-1):
            newList.append(measurements[j][i])

newArray = rotate90(measurements)
```

I get "none" as an output when I run this code. I am not allowed to use numpy for this question.

Comment: `rotate90()` does not have a `return` statement, so of course it returns `None` as a default value.  Perhaps you meant to have `return newList` at the end?

Comment: Also as a performance improvement you can restrict N to the range 0-3, because four rotations of 90 would end up with the same original grid.

Answer (score 1):

You have several mistakes in your code. For starters, your function doesn't output anything since you're missing a `return` statement.

Then your logic is incorrect, you don't use the correct indices and the correct order. A fix of your code could be:

```
def rotate90(measurements):
    N = len(measurements)
    newList = []
    for i in range(N-1, -1, -1):
        tmp = []
        for j in range(N):
            tmp.append(measurements[j][i])
        newList.append(tmp)
    return newList
```

Now to repeat the process.

If you want to rotate a 2D list counter-clockwise N times, you only need to think of how to do it for N in 1-4. Then the process restarts. Here is an example with a different approach to rotate:

```
def rotate90(inpt, N=0):
    N = N%4
    if N == 0: # unchanged
        return inpt
    if N == 1: # rotate counter-clockwise
        return list(map(list, zip(*inpt)))[::-1]
    if N == 2: # reverse on both axes
        return [x[::-1] for x in inpt[::-1]]
    if N == 3:  # rotate clockwise
        return list(map(list, zip(*inpt[::-1])))
```

Examples:

```
lst = [[4, 3, 1],
       [6, 5, 2],
       [9, 7, 3],]

rotate90(lst, 0)
# [[4, 3, 1],
#  [6, 5, 2],
#  [9, 7, 3]]

rotate90(lst, 1)
# [[1, 2, 3],
#  [3, 5, 7],
#  [4, 6, 9]]

rotate90(lst, 2)
# [[3, 7, 9],
#  [2, 5, 6],
#  [1, 3, 4]]

rotate90(lst, 3)
# [[9, 6, 4],
#  [7, 5, 3],
#  [3, 2, 1]]

rotate90(lst, 4)
# [[4, 3, 1],
#  [6, 5, 2],
#  [9, 7, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are couple of modifications you could make. I'm not aware in which platform you are implementing the solution, so you might need to modify how data is written into the program, and how it is returned as output.

In the code below, I print out the resulting grid, though you might want to return it as part of some function, depending on your task.

```
def rotate_grid(grid):
    """
    Rotate the grid by 90 degrees clockwise.
    """
    return [[grid[j][i] for j in range(len(grid))] for i in range(len(grid[0]) - 1, -1, -1)]

def print_grid(grid):
    """
    Print the grid to stdout.
    """
    for row in grid:
        print(' '.join(map(str, row)))

def main():
    # Ask for dimensions of the grid
    dimension = int(input("Enter dimension of the grid: "))
    grid = [[0] * dimension for _ in range(dimension)]

    # Populate the grid
    print("Enter the numbers for each cell separated by space:")
    for i in range(dimension):
        for j in range(dimension):
            grid[i][j] = int(input(f"Enter number for cell ({i+1}, {j+1}): "))

    print("\nOriginal Grid:")
    print_grid(grid)

    # Ask for the number of rotations
    rotations = int(input("Enter number of 90-degree rotations: "))

    # Rotate the grid
    for _ in range(rotations):
        grid = rotate_grid(grid)

    print("\nRotated Grid:")
    print_grid(grid)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The script prompts the user to specify the dimension of a grid and then input numbers for each cell. After populating the grid, it asks for the number of 90-degree clockwise rotations desired. It then performs the rotations and prints both the original and rotated grids to the standard output. This is accomplished using functions to rotate the grid and print it, along with a main function to orchestrate the user interaction and grid manipulation.